# Failed to start Raise network interfaces on ubuntu 16.04.01

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I am running ubuntu 16.04 (fresh install) with the networking interface configured on dhcp inside virtualbox. This worked perfectly on that box until recently and works still perfect for another box.

Suddently I am having trouble raising the network interface enp0s17. I have another interface configured with static IP that works OK.

/etc/network/interfaces looks like this:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp0s8 enp0s17

iface enp0s17 inet dhcp

iface enp0s8 inet static
        address 192.143.56.200
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.143.56.0
        broadcast 192.143.56.255
        dns-nameservers 192.143.56.1
```

Syslog shows this:

```
Jan 29 07:17:36 rex dhclient[1091]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s17 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0xaf741468)
Jan 29 07:17:36 rex sh[1079]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s17 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0xaf741468)
Jan 29 07:17:50 rex systemd[1]: networking.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jan 29 07:17:50 rex systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Jan 29 07:17:50 rex systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 29 07:17:50 rex systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jan 29 07:17:50 rex systemd[1]: Reached target Network.
```

The config looks OK to me and not different to the point where it used to work.

What I did before is to configure iptables, but have deleted the rule and checked it if it is really deleted. The name of the interface seems to be OK:

```
 sudo ifconfig -a
 enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:4f:d8:fb  
           inet addr:192.143.56.200  Bcast:192.143.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
           inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe4f:d8fb/64 Scope:Link
           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           RX packets:4098 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:3693 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
           RX bytes:303862 (303.8 KB)  TX bytes:373908 (373.9 KB)

 enp0s17   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:1a:5e:6c  
           inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe1a:5e6c/64 Scope:Link
           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           RX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:59 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
           RX bytes:276 (276.0 B)  TX bytes:18090 (18.0 KB)
```

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I've wasted like a whole day trying to figure why static network configuration won't work consistently. Then dumped it, went with `nmcli` and never looked back. It's so much better and reliable.

It's funny coz originally I was the kind of guy whose first step was erasing networkmanager right after install. Now I couldn't live without it.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue after I imported  virtual box image to VMware.
after lot of time, the solution that worked.

1. first find out what interfaces are available on the machine

   ## ip link

this would list the interfaces, I had lo and ens32 listed. [[no eth0 or eth1]]. the Mac address of ens32 matched that of my ethernet card.

2. next,

   ## cat /etc/network/interfaces

check what it says.

You need to ensure the interface we found in step 1. i.e ens32 is listed here.

I changed the primary network card section as below.

## the primary network interface

auto ens32
iface ens32 net dhcp
      headdress ether 00:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

replace your Mac address above

save the file

3. restart networking

   ## sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

that should do. good luck. and thanks for the samaritan who saved me here.